# How to change certificate with fingerprint for console google play on Visual Studio for Mac using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play-console

Last week I upload a bundle from play console successfully.
Today I want to upload the same bundle with some updates and I receive a message:

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:

SHA1: F9:C8:1E:A9:5B:DD:D2:46:CF:6F:79:46:EB:45:97:6E:94:6A:62:E1

but the certificate used to sign the app bundle that you uploaded has fingerprint:

SHA1: 61:7B:10:17:B3:80:FD:70:44:FB:9C:FB:3D:DC:F9:22:BC:A9:45:16
```

What can I do to deploy successfully my bundle on **Visual Studio for Mac**.

When I use this command in terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I see this one in the terminal:

```
    Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Apr 7, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 5ebc7130
Valid from: Wed Apr 07 12:17:19 EEST 2021 until: Fri Mar 31 12:17:19 EEST 2051
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 61:7B:10:17:B3:80:FD:70:44:FB:9C:FB:3D:DC:F9:22:BC:A9:45:16
     SHA256: 96:B7:D4:F7:23:BC:AB:6F:06:5D:90:F5:B1:CC:E8:13:E4:DC:48:3E:38:70:60:9B:E0:BC:DE:4D:9B:CE:79:A9
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 9C AC A3 9A 44 C3 C2 B8   0A 83 A5 60 29 47 21 AB  ....D......`)G!.
0010: 55 85 48 AA                                        U.H.
]
]
```

Comment: is "androiddebugkey" the one you used for the **Play Store Submission**, or do you have other keyfiles that you've forgotten about?  You can also have multiple keys in a file - there in an option in `keytool` to list them all

Comment: I use androiddebugkey.. but how to see where is it .. I can't find in library/developer/xamarin directory

Comment: search your entire machine for keystore files

Comment: The solution is: Re Sign In when you want to save the bundle on the disk.. enter the password again and the bundle file is resign in with the new certificate..